# "Closed interval" on ordered topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be linearly ordered by a relation $\leq$. Taking as a subbase for topology on $X$ all sets of the form $\{x;x<a\}$ and $\{x;x>a\}$, for $a\in X$. Can be $\{x\in X; a\leq x\leq b\}$ a open set, for $a<b$, in $X$?

I think the answer is no, beause $\{x\in X; a\leq x\leq b\}^c=\{x;x<b\}\cup\{x;x>a\}$ is a open set.

Its correct?

Comment: I don't disagree with your answer but your proof is certainly not sufficient. In general just because the complement of a set is open doesn't mean the set isn't open. It just means the set is closed.

Comment: I understood, but in any way this set cannot be open, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be open. Think of the set $[0,1]$ with the order inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ and the topology you describe. Then think of the set $\{x;0\leq x \leq 1\}$.

Comment: Another example I think is $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ with the usual order. Then without too much work you can see that every singleton is open in the ray topology (for non endpoints just take an intersection of a ray from just above to just below for endpoints just take the ray from just above or just below). Then $\{1,2,3\}=\{x;1\leq x\leq 3\}$ is open as a finite union of open sets.

Comment: Any discrete topology would work as example, non?

Comment: @arash ^what he said.:) Except I suppose not every discrete topology can be written as a result of a subbasis of rays? Or at least not without AC maybe?

Comment: Yup, for a concrete example for OP just take $X = \mathbb{Z}$ with the topology he gave.

Comment: Guys I'm lost, AC? OP? Can I prove in general way that $\{x; a\leq x\leq b\}$ is a open set?

Comment: OP just means "original post" or "original poster" (i.e. you). AC means "Axiom of choice" but you can safely ignore that bit. I will write up a short answer for you that summarises the results so far though I'm sure it won't be all encompassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is "Yes, $\{x\in X;\;a\leq x\leq b\}$ for $a<b$ can be an open set."

There are a number of ways this can happen. The trivial but slightly boring one is if your order has endpoints $a$, and $b$ such that $\forall x\in X\; a\leq x$ and $\forall x\in X\; b\geq x$. Then $X=\{x;a\leq x\leq b\}$ and is open. An example of this is $[0,1]$ with the order inherited form $\mathbb{R}$.

A less trivial example is any linear order which is at least partially discrete. This just means you have a few points such that there is nothing between them. A small example would be $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ ordered the usual way (with order inherited from $\mathbb{N}$. In this case every singleton is open. We will just quickly show it for $\{2\}$. We can take the open sets $\{x;x>1\}$ and $\{x;x<3\}$ their intersection is open and is exactly $\{2\}$. Since the union of open sets is open every set in this topology is open (it is the discrete topology) and thus in particular the set $\{x;1\leq x\leq 2\}$ is open for example.

This second argument can be extended to arbitrary linear orders for which the ray topology gives us a discrete topological space (I believe these are exactly the discrete linear orders but I might be wrong something strange might happen with tricky enough orders like say $\omega\times \mathbb{Z}$). Certainly an easy example of a bigger space which is discrete under the ray topology is $\mathbb{Z}$ and for it all the sets you describe will be open.